# Custom Login page with JSF doesn't work in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I've guided from this [post](http://ocpsoft.org/java/acegi-spring-security-jsf-login-page/) but I can't enter to homepage(/pages/admin/listAdmin.xhtml) of my webapp. Login page doesn't redirect me

PD: /pages/admin/listAdmin.xhtml is mapped to /a1/ with PrettyFaces

My XML file configuration:

[XML file](http://pastebin.com/iFGvPdSU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I did following change in my login button (I'm working with Primefaces)

I only added the parameter `ajax="false"` to my button component

```
<p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Ingresar" type="submit"
                        action="#{loginController.loginOn}" ajax="false"/>
```